# Take SharePoint Site Url from user when they connect to my App

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

When I try to connect an app from https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/?product=power-bi
for example the GitHub app. It will ask for Repository Owner and GitHub repository name.

[image]

How do I take these type of parameter when user connect to my published app?

Thanks.